# Get Model Properties ( DB column )

Tags: model, resource-model

Is it possible to get a list of the table columns that are related to a model ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to use the `describeTable()` method.

So your resource model, you can create a function as the following one, this will return an array of fields for the main table:

```
public function getFields()
{
    $fields = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: I like this method - and great with the self-answer. I was going to suggest Zend_Db_Table's `info(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::COLS)` method, but this is great and works within the bounds of pure Magento.

Comment: Thanks, I just dig 10 min in the classes hierarchy of model/resource model and I end up in `describeTable()` method, to be precise here: `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::hasDataChanged()`
( I usually challenge myself writing question and try to be faster that the community answer :)

Answer (score 1):

For who are struggling with this in Magento 2:

In your custom **resource model class**, add this function:

```
public function getFields()
{
    $fields = $this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
    return $fields;
}
```

And in somewhere you need to get all columns of a table (all fields of object):

```
$objectModel = $this->objectFactory->create(); // I prefer using dependency injection
$keys = array_keys($objectModel->getResource()->getFields());
```

P/S: Thank you @Fra for a great self-answer question. It saved a lot of my time.